# Problems while setting up a simple UDP server

Tags: c, sockets

I'm going into sockets programming in C, but I have a problem that -I'm sure- it's coming from my confusion: How can I set up a server using *getaddrinfo()*, and how to get it's address from a client? I'm using UDP.

(I come from [Beej's tutorial](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html), but I still not understand that)

This is the code of my server (I'm trying to run it at *mhgc.net* and port 3051, although I haven't found the way to set the... hostname? Sorry, I'm confused):

```
int sockd;

/* Get my IP address */
struct addrinfo hints, * servinfo;
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;  // use my own address
if( getaddrinfo(NULL, "3051", &hints, &servinfo) != 0 ) {
    /* Yes, below is not... 'pretty code'; this is just an attempt */
    errorf("Failed to get server address: %s", gai_strerror( getaddrinfo(NULL, "3051", &hints, &servinfo) ));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    return 1;
}

struct addrinfo * p = NULL;
for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
    if( (sockd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1 ) {
        perror("Cannot open socket");
        continue;
    }

    if(bind(sockd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
        close(sockd);
        perror("Cannot bind to port");
        continue;
    }

    break;
}

if(p == NULL) {
    error("listener: failed to bind socket");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    return 0;
}

freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

struct sockaddr_storage clientinfo;
socklen_t clientinfo_len = sizeof(clientinfo);

char buffer[15];
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
if( recvfrom(sockd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&clientinfo, &clientinfo_len) == -1 ) {
    perror("Error receiving packet");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    return 0;
}

char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
printf("listener: got packet from %s\n", inet_ntop(clientinfo.ss_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&clientinfo), s, sizeof(s)));
printf("listener: packet contains \"%s\"\n", buffer);

/* Close the socket descriptor */
close(sockd);

    /* And now, exit, or whatever I need ... ... ... */
```

and for my client:

```
int sockd;

struct addrinfo hints, * servinfo;
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
//hints.ai_flags = AI_CANONNAME;
if( getaddrinfo(MKS_HOSTNAME, "www", &hints, &servinfo) != 0 ) {
    errorf("Failed to get server address: %s", gai_strerror( getaddrinfo(NULL, "3051", &hints, &servinfo) ));
    return 1;
}

struct addrinfo * p = NULL;
for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
    if((sockd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
        perror("Cannot open socket");
        continue;
    }

    break;
}

if(p == NULL) {
    error("talker: failed to bind socket");
    return 2;
}

if( sendto(sockd, "this-is-a-test", strlen("this-is-a-test")+1, 0, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1 ) {
    perror("Error sending packet");
    return 1;
}

freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

close(sockd);
```

*error* and *errorf* are macros to help me debugging the application. Don't worry about them.

Another tip, if you allow me: talker.c, from Beej's tutorial, uses a hostname to 'find' the server. I downloaded listener.c and talker.c, compiled it (make listener && make talker) but, I didn't know what to pass as talker argument. What is the hostname of listener? How can I find it? Sorry again. I'm really confused about that :S

Working on Debian GNU/Linux "squeeze", using gcc compiler v4.4.5

Answer (score 0):

On the server, if you don't want to listen to a specific address, simply pass the `any` address (all address element set to zero). Your call to `getaddrinfo` in order to get the local address will never give you a reasonable answer. Set the `service` parameter to `NULL` since you want to know the IP address of a host, not the name of the service.

To connect the client to the server, either use the IP address of the server (execute `/sbin/ifconfig` on the server and search for an address that is reachable by the client) or it's host name (i.e. execute `hostname` on the server and use that name on the client for connecting the server).

Comment: Thank you! I finally got it yesterday night, I slept happy :) . There was a "problem" with the DNS domain name of my computer (not code/firewall issue) so, when I pass it as first argument of _getaddrinfo()_,... it just doesn't find the host. I put the "gross" IP address of my machine... and get it! Thanks again for your answer